# I want to crawl contests detail from hackerrank but i am unable to do this by beautifulsoup library, can anyone suggest another way to do the same?

Tags: web-crawler

I want to **crawl** contests detail from hackerrank but i am unable to do this by beautifulsoup library, can anyone suggest another way to do the same?

Comment: i also dont know :P

Comment: This is not a good question for SO.  What language are you using? (I see Python based on the library...)  Why doesn't the library work for you?

Comment: yea i am using python and library doesn't working because data that i want to crawl is dynamic.Can you suggest or tell me how to crawl dynamic data of a website using python or java. Thanks :) @Joshua

Comment: There are several issues here.  The first is variation in page content.  Do you want the details page like https://www.hackerrank.com/101hack44? That is all available as HTML.  Convoluted maybe, but still scrapable. Or do you want the details like https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges?  Which is "dynamic".  The later simply requires calling the correct endpoint.  You could find the content here: https://www.hackerrank.com/rest/contests/projecteuler/challenges?offset=0&limit=10&filters=:true+page:1&track_login=true&_=1480515336704 so, this question, as is is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

for crawling,you need the page source to have html content,since hackerrank data is dynamic therefore you cant crawl through BeautifulSoup

Comment: Is there any other method to crawl dynamic data? @meghna